# is reference block inside reference block is a good thing or bad?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, query

Before anything, I already searched this online and didn't find anything satisfactory.

I was working on a project where I had to add an extra column in order items section of every place.

Everything was working fine I added the column everywhere including in the admin section of order view page.

In this section, I add the extra field by increasing an extra attribute to the sales_order_view.xml layout file, added the code below,

```
<referenceBlock name="order_items">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="product_type" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Type</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>

    <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product_type" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-product_type</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn"
               name="column_product_type" template="Custom_CustomColumnInItems::order/items/product_type.phtml" group="column" />
</referenceBlock>
```

and it's working fine, but then one of the senior's pinout the point that referenceBlock inside the referenceBlock is never seen before.

So My question is, **Is the referenceBlock inside the referenceBlock is allowed and legal in magento2 or not?**

Am I allowed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of `<referenceBlock></referenceBlock>` recursive is not good.

From a developer perspective, it seems very bad and looks odd.

> Is the referenceBlock inside the referenceBlock is allowed

But it is not supported at Magento2.  If this type is allowed then there is no use `<move>` and `<remove>` etc.

Comment: hmm, then It means I have to find another way to implement this. 
Can you also suggest how can we add an extra column in order_view section in admin? or 
what will be the preferred way to write this.